# How to export .xyz files from VESTA of crystal viewed along different crystallographic axes

Tags: software, vesta

I've only been able to export atomic coordinates for a crystal when looking down the c axis, but I need to do so along the a and b axis as well. I've tried changing the Projection Vector in the Orientation window, but this didn't change the exported data at all.

Comment: Use the commands `edit`>`edit data`>`unit cell`>`Transform`

Comment: @pranavkumar even if you just have a simple answer, its probably better to have it as an answer rather than a comment. If you think its too basic a question or that you aren't able to provide a fully detailed answer, setting the answer as "community wiki" will better preserve the content while implicitly marking it as "in progress" and open to edits from other users.

Answer (score 5):

Orientation window will change only the view but it will not rotate the data as coordinate axis remain same even orientation window changes. If you want to swap axis for e.g z with y or any other custom vector. It will be necessary to rotate the unit cell using transformation matrix. Inside VESTA, kindly follow this step.

```
edit>edit data>unit cell>Transform
```

There are other tools such as `vaspkit`, `atomsk`which can quick swap vectors of unit cell.
for example:

**1. atomsk**

```
atomsk initial.cfg -swap X Y final.xsf
```

**2. VASPKIT**
VASPKIT (407) can do swap two axis of lattice vector.